# How to remove back button from navigation bar?

Tags: android

I thought that is a solution for that but I cannot find it. I know that I can disable back button by overriding `onBackPress()` method and not call `super.onBackPress()` but it only disable, I want to remove/hide from navigation bar this button.

And I known that on some device where the back button is a part of hardware it can be done.

To be clear I mean arrow on below screen:

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but you could hide it (complete nav bar)

Comment: You need root for this.  YOu can hide the entire nav bar, but not just the back button without it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find solution in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation).

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

and this code should be placed in `onCreate()` method in the `Activity` after initializing all UI elements.

Comment: this code hide all navigation buttons. I want to hide/remove only one: back button

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your onCreate() method : to hide 
    [image]

```
View bView = getWindow().getDecorView();
bView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```